# Beginner Encryption, "Master Password" Question

Tags: c#, aes, password-encryption

I'm writing a program that, using Rijndael, will encrypt and decrypt files/folders using a user chosen password. Currently, when the user wants to encrypt something, they have to enter a password, that password is used to encrypt and when the user is ready to, decrypt the file/folder.

However, I would like to have a "master password" that will allow the user to only enter the password once in a "preferences" portion of the program, and then the program will automatically use that password for all encryption/decryption. This way they don't have to put in a password every time they want to encrypt/decrypt.

Now, since programs like this are prone to many different kinds of attacks, how do I safely store the user's "master password" so someone couldn't get a hold of it? Storing it in the program in plain text is obviously not a good idea, so I could encrypt/decrypt the password with ***another*** password, chosen by me, and stored in the program.

However, again, if someone gets access to the password chosen by me to encrypt/decrypt the master password, then they could decrypt the master password and again, that wouldn't be good.

SO! How do programs safely do this?

**Currently I'm saving the "master password" by encrypting it using my own, chosen password, and storing it in a User-scoped setting. If you think this isn't a good idea, please tell me why and what would you change about the process I currently have implemented?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know why websites won't tell you your password when you lost it and they ask for a new one?
Because they don't know it. Yes, they don't know it. They hash it and hash it good so they can only check your input password's hash against the one in the database.

Why all that?
Because they cannot store it safely.
They cannot encrypt it safely.

This is a similar case.
The best way is not to use a master password.

When you encrypt a file, ask for a password and encrypt with the hash of the password.
When decrypting, **do** ask for a password and attempt to decrypt.
If it fails then it's wrong.
If it's okay then it's the right one.

You can add some (shorter) dummy data before the file's contents that you can use to check the key.

---

If you try to use that to store the master password, you will enter an infinite loop of security, which is not a good idea.
You'll encrypt the password, and then encrypt the key used and then encrypt the key used to encrypt the first key etc.

**Edit**: I am sorry about the discouraging nature of this answer but what you need to do is truly impossible.

Comment: I've noticed the infinite, circular pattern myself. If I do implement a master password, I suppose I'll protect it as securely as I can, and leave it be. The program is only for my enjoyment anyway.

Comment: If you roll up a pretty good program you might actually make some profit, if you can/are interested. By the way, if you do publish it, consider adding a warning that you cannot protect the master password.

Comment: I was waiting to see if any other answers popped up. Looks like not.

Answer (score 3):

Review this:
http://www.redkestrel.co.uk/Articles/StoringSecrets.html

It's a great article on your options.

That said, I think your use case is already pretty well natively covered by windows itself through EFS....
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700811.aspx

Just wanted to add one thing:
It is fundamentally impossible to protect a "secret" from those who have physical access to the machine.  This has been [proven](http://www.net-security.org/secworld.php?id=9077) [time](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13578_3-9876060-38.html) and [again](http://hackaday.com/2008/02/21/breaking-disk-encryption-with-ram-dumps/) even for hard drives that support native encryption schemes.

All you can do is make it somewhat difficult for those that have no idea what they are doing.

The fundamental problem is that something has to have access to the decryption key.  Whether it's the BIOS of the machine, Firmware of the Harddrive, or even if it's stored in some folder hidden through DPAPI.  Which means the only effective way is to force the user to supply the necessary credentials when it's time to encrypt / decrypt the files.

If those credentials are sufficiently short then it's possible to use brute force to get to them.  Right now the recommendation is to use minimum key lengths of 128 bits or greater.  Of course, if you are limited to use common letters then the number of bits to test goes down dramatically.  And if you allow values such as those found in hacking dictionaries then the time to crack goes down further.

Another wrinkle are keyloggers.  If one's installed (and they can be hidden from most users) then all an attacker has to do is wait for the user to type their decryption password in and forward that to an interested party.

Heck, for the truly paranoid, there are devices that can detect what you typed based solely on the sound your keyboard makes as you type.  For others, RAM maintains state for a certain period of time even after the machine has been shut off...

So, what does all this mean?  First, you have to ask them to provide the credentials on each encrypt / decrypt request.  Second, they have to be sure that no keyloggers are installed.  Third, the credentials can't be something easily remembered.  Fourth, the computer cannot be in a physically accessible location.  Fifth, even the keyboard has to be secured...

All of which adds up to a situation that says if its on a computer, someone else can get it.

Comment: How can file encryption prevent programs/readers/decompilers from opening the assembly and get his password?

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to store the hash value and compare when the user re-enters the password. Would you recommend a specific hash algorithm?

Comment: @CODe: Note that storing a hash is no solution to your problem. A hash is created using a one-way function and you won't be able to restore the original password from its hashed value. However, in order to be able to DEcrypt you are going to need an unhashed password/key.

Comment: @Vercas: He is building software whose purpose is to allow the user to select files to encrypt / decrypt.  This is already built into the OS and so I'm questioning the reasoning behind writing a piece of software that already exists, ships with windows, and has had a large team of smart people trying to figure out the best way to protect those secrets.  And whose solution to the problem is held deep in the core of the OS.

Comment: @Chris Lively EFS does **not** ask you for a password (NOR A KEY) when trying to open the files! If it did then people wouldn't use/develop apps to do that!

Comment: @0xA3: True, I jumped the gun a bit on the information in that article. Back to square one. Thanks for picking that up. +1

Comment: @Vercas: It's based off of your Windows password, which windows asks for when you log into the machine....  Basically they ask that you provide the secret to get access to the store and cache that for the length of your computing session

Comment: @Chris Lively This is why people roll up their own file encryption software. It is used to **password protect files** actually, which Windows unfortunately does not provide (not sure about other OSes).

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing you master password in memory using the [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) Class.

Comment: This partially solves the problem of protecting the data in memory, but doesn't nothing for persisted storage nor for when the program needs to load it from that storage.

Comment: I'm against the idea of persisting credentials into storage media.

Comment: @Chris: What if I created a SecureString object as a User-scoped setting, this way it would persist? I'm not quite familiar with SecureString, so I could be a bit misguided here...

Comment: @Islam: I need the password to persist in some form or fashion, otherwise it's useless.

Comment: SecureString has nothing to do with persisting password into storage. What's the problem with using NTFS file encryption?

Comment: @Islam: You mean EFS? Because I'm writing a program to jump into encryption head first because it's interesting to me. I know SecureString doesn't have anything to do with persistence, which is why I was recommending a SecureString as a user-scoped setting which are automatically persisted. A master password that is lost when the program closes wouldn't be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be frank about this. Leave security to security experts. Security is not easy, and is very very hard to get right even for people who are supposedly experts in the area.

If you really have to store sensitive data that your users are expecting to be secure then asking in SO on *how to do it* is definitely NOT a good sign and not the way to go. You should seek professional guidance or consider using well tested implementations available in the market or in Windows itself.

Comment: How do you think those experts came to be? Do you think some people are born with the skills needed to be security experts? They learn, through experience. This is what I'm trying to do, and this program isn't being used by anyone except for myself, it's solely for my experience. You'd be better off answering questions rather than telling people to avoid doing something just because they haven't before. People come on SO and ask questions to gain experience and solve problems, if you don't wish to help, then don't answer.

Comment: @CODe You'll see that 90% of your answers are and will be discouragement.

Comment: @Vercas: Well I'm glad there are other people on SO, besides those that only offer discouragement, that are willing to help and share their knowledge rather than discouraging newcomers from learning something they know little about.

Comment: @CODe I hate the whole "leave it to the experts" shit. This prevents other potential experts from forming and thus killing the domain. But the experts disagree, because of the money and/or selfishness.

Comment: Whatever. False security is worse than no security at all, and believe me, no security expert is self taught or an expert in this area of expertise by learning in a public forum. But it's not my problem, it's just my advice.

Comment: @InBetween: Whatever? Thanks for your contribution, another great addition to this problem. Do you think I'm only using SO to learn about cryptography? Do you think that when I can't find an answer on SO, I don't go to Google and read articles and do research? Your logic is flawed and your advice is unhelpful. You should go somewhere else if you have a "but it's not my problem" attitude, I'm sure most people will welcome the absence.

Answer (score 0):

Don't persist the user's password, take a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash) and be sure to [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) it. Use the hash to encrypt and decrypt the files. Beware if the user forgets their password you will not be able to recover it for them however you could still decrypt the files for them. This also means your app would be vulnerable to somebody hacking/patching it to get it to decrypt files without providing the password.

If the encryption method is standard, documented, obvious and/or well-known then to prevent hackers from just reading the hash and using it to decrypt the files themselves you could do this: use the stored hash along with some other info to generate a new hash that you then use to encrypt/decrypt the files and never persist. The other info could be made up of the size of the file, the created date, etc. Hackers could use this info but they would have to hack/reverse engineer your app before they know they need it. Technically it's security through obscurity since those keys are hidden in plain view.

Comment: It won't be vulnerable to that if the program was signed with a private/public key pair.

Comment: @Gordy: So, I take the hash of the password and use that to encrypt and decrypt. How is this different from storing the password itself? Hackers can now, instead of getting the password, can get the hash and use it to decrypt all the "protected" files.

Comment: Roll your own encryption method that the hackers will never figure out! :)

Comment: The experts are right but it's a lot of fun to roll your own. Fundamentally you can't be secure in this scenario. The best you will achieve is security-through-obscurity and what's more obscure than homegrown encryption - just be sure to base it on [elliptic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography) and not bit-bashing.

Comment: @CODe: That is precisely mistaken security and why you should be looking for professional guidance for this kind of stuff. If the hacker has access to where you are storing your password then you have already lost the war to begin with, there is no defense against that. The whole point of salting and hashing the password is not to stop hackers from reaching it, its done in order to stop dictionary attacks and in case of a serious security breach,  hackers will have no clue of what the real password is, which with high probability, is used by the exposed user in countless other places.

Comment: and that is why it is also a good idea to *salt* the password with something specific to the user and application before hashing it. That way you are also ensuring that the hashed password is also with an almost 100% probability unique to your application for any given user.

Comment: @InBetween: Thank you! I appreciate the advice and have what you mentioned implemented, even though it was done prior to reading this. Currently I have the salt being generated randomly and persisted for each user, because, unfortunately, I have no details about each user.